# Is there anything to keep in mind when choosing Boo for Unity development?

Tags: unity, boo

I just noticed that Unity has Boo as a compatible language but I haven't seen any tutorials using Boo nor any games. I love Python and would like to code in its syntax - maybe for a small project. Because I haven't seen much Booscript around, I fear that there is lack of support. Is there anything I should be wary of before venturing down this obscure road?

Comment: Edited to remove the question about whether or not projects written in Boo exist. It's just industry trivia and I feel it was not really the focus of your main question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to keep this in mind:

> This means that, as so few people use Boo, and the resources required
>   to support it in the docs are not negligible, we’ve decided to drop
>   support for Boo documentation for the Unity 5.0 release and use our
>   resources in a more constructive way.
>
> When Unity 5.0 launches, we will also drop “Create Boo Script” from
>   the menu. That said, and very importantly, if your project contains
>   Boo scripts, they will still work just as before.

http://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/09/03/documentation-unity-scripting-languages-and-you/

It's unlikely that Boo will be around in Unity with support for much longer now. For a small personal project I guess it's fine, but for something bigger I would not consider writing Boo under Unity to be a worthwhile investment. At the very least, the lack of documentation will hit you quite a bit in the long run *now*.

With Boo's grim future out of the way...

---

> Is there anything I should be wary of before venturing down this obscure road?

As long as you're aware of how the language works [compared to C#](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:2xeR60CAG4UJ:boo.codehaus.org/Differences%2Bwith%2BCsharp%20&cd=1&hl=ro&ct=clnk&gl=ro) or UnityScript, it's okay. All three languages compile to the same thing after all, and Unity lets you use all three at the same time as long as you meet some conditions (making sure C# code is compiled before your Boo code in order to reference it from Boo scripts for example).

In short: use Boo if you want, and in case you ever reach the need of some feature that C# has and Boo doesn't, write that feature in C# and use it from Boo.

You *should* be able to translate code between the languages yourself though. Boo isn't the most popular choice so it's wise to be able to turn the C# code you find around the web that solves some problem you have into Boo.

Comment: Oh, that's a bit disappointing. For an engine like Unity, I think they're better off doing it right or not doing it at all - and I guess doing Boo right would take more effort than what it's worth. Thanks for the research and links. I'll stick to the boring path trodden on :'(.